# Indexes in Google Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

By default indexing is enabled for all the fields in the ndb based model class.

What if I change the indexing definition for a field and redeploy the app; will it drop the indexing or recreate it,  for that field, based on the changes in the model class?

Or is it like entity relationships which can't be changed once defined. I am asking this because, I am not sure at this point,  how many fields I would require to be indexed in the final application ?

Comment: I find a good way to discover things like this is to experiment. You might as well find out for yourself, if you can, rather then ask a random person on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for advice ! This a valid answer to at least 95% of the questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: this is true. As you run queries on your app locally it generates an index.yaml https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig where it notes " You only need to edit the file manually to delete indexes that are no longer used, or to define indexes not created by the development web server". So it should sort itself out as you deploy as per that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at any time change the definition of an entity object, the important thing is whether the property is set to be indexed when you put(). Say I have inserted a bunch of objects with a "name" property, un-indexed. Later I add an index to future put()'s on those entities. All my entities will still be in the datastore, just the ones that were indexed are query-able. A similar logic applies when I remove indexing from a language-local model property (java @Entity class for example, with objectify), and then do put().

This is what it means to have a schemaless datastore. They can have all different combinations of properties and indexing on/off for each of them. The only thing that truly binds these entities together is their "kind", which is set to the classname by the framework you're using, or set by hand if you're using the truly low-level API.

[Read more here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Python_Unindexed_properties) to understand better how indexing works in the schemaless datastore. This answers your question completely if you read the section linked.